# Mudanças diretamente no banco de dados refletem no managed bean?

Tags: mysql, jpa-2.0, jsf-2.2

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web simples, um formulário. Fiz os DAO's, Facades e elas estão funcionando corretamente (pelo menos eu acho que estão) porém vou precisar também editar alguns valores diretamente no banco só que essas mudanças não estão sendo refletidas na aplicação, por exemplo, o banco contém a coluna "matricula do aluno" com o valor 20, e esse valor é carregado e exibido normalmente na aplicação, ao fazer a edição do valor pela a aplicação o valor é editado normalmente, mas ao realizar a edição manual (substituir 20 por 30 diretamente no banco por exemplo) e recarregar a view, o JSF passa por todos os métodos necessários (um método init() anotado com @PostConstruct) mas não exibe o valor alterado e sim o valor antigo.

Já tentei com @RequestScoped e @ViewScoped. Isso é normal?

Estou usando JSF2.2, EclipseLink, MySQL e JPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, verifique se a alteração está isolada em uma transação não efetivada. Se estiver, faça o `commit` para os valores serem lidos corretamente pela aplicação.

Pode ainda estar ocorrendo do valores estarem em *cache*.

Se for o *cache* normal do JPA, execute o método `refresh()` do `EntityManager` passando as entidades a serem atualizadas. Os valores serão recarregados do banco de dados.

Se você usa algum tipo de *second level cache*, você pode limpar esse *cache* com o seguinte método:

```java
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```

Ou, especificamente para uma entidade, use o método:

```java
entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(
        classeEntidade, 
        valorChavePrimaria);
```

Veja a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cache.html).

Answer (score 0):

Após a edição diretamente no banco de dados, reinicie o seu servidor de aplicação e recarregue a view. Como já experimentei este mesmo 'problema', vi que após reiniciar o servidor (no meu caso o Tomcat) a aplicação passou a 'ver' aquelas alterações feitas. Mas realmente procuro por uma solução mais ideal.